# (RESOLVED in V13.1) Failing to import a TGF file of a graph with no edges (V12.x and V13.0)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs, import

**Bug persisting through 13.0**

---

Version: 12.x and 13.0

I am having an issue with importing a graph stored in the Trivial Graph Format (TGF) when the graph has no edges. Consider the following:

```
graph=Graph[{1,2,3},{}]; (*Graph with 3 vertices and no edges between them*)
Export["test.tgf",graph];
```

The Export is successful and a correctly formatted TGF file is produced. However,

```
Import["test.tgf"]
```

returns various errors.

The same errors are encountered when the TGF file is produced outside of Mathematica.

There is no error when the graph has at least one edge.

I would appreciate any known workarounds.

Update: after reporting to Mathematica as suggested in the comments, the issue has been acknowledged and forwarded to the developers. A proposed workaround was to use the .g6 format instead of .tgf

Update 2: Wolfram Tech Support informed me that this has been resolved as of v13.1.

Comment: Please report this to Wolfram. Unfortunately, every single graph writer in Mathematica is buggy in some way, and so are some graph readers. I usually try to use GML or come up with my own tabular format.